# Count *.plot files in certain directories on network filesystems

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, file-system

First of all, I am playing around with python for about a week tops. Absolute beginner here.

My story:
I work as an IT administrator so I am familiar with eg. PS on a very basic level. I actually got into python due to the fact that I am plotting/farming chia. Now a rather long holiday is coming up, so I thought to myself I might as well write a discord bot with a couple of commands that would allow me to monitor pc resourcer, perhaps initiate PC restarts and etc....

Now I got a couple of functions done including the one I want to ask about, this script is giving back the number of files on the specified locations with the extension .plot.

First of all, this script is doing what I want it to do. However! Its very static, meaning I actually set locations in variables, which is good for now, but in the perfect scenario it would certinaly not list files with .plot extension should they be in any other location.

My second concern is that even though I have used functions to connect to my samba server (which is running on a PI4) I have a feeling this part of the code is not being used. And as long as I previously autechnicated against the IP shares on windows my script would work with the "cached" credentials.

All in all here is my code, it is probably a HUGE mess, but! could you please provide some insight on specific parts of the code to make it better, "more professional" so to say.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import os

from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"  #ip or domain name to SMB server
username="***"          #SAMBA server username
password="xxxxx"        #SAMBA server password
sharename="\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\chia1"
sharename2="\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\chia2"
sharename3="I:"
conn=SMBConnection(username,password,"","",use_ntlm_v2 = True)
result = conn.connect(host, 445)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sharename):
    for Files in files:
        if Files.endswith(".plot"):
            totalfiles += 1

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sharename2):
    for Files in files:
        if Files.endswith(".plot"):
            totalfiles += 1

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sharename3):
    for Files in files:
        if Files.endswith(".plot"):
            totalfiles += 1

result = ":page_facing_up: Total number of plots: "

printoutput = ('{}{}'.format(result, totalfiles))

print('{}{}'.format(result, totalfiles))
```

Answer (score 5):

It's generally a very bad idea to put credentials in a program. That's
a bigger topic, and the best approach will vary depending on your situation.
But you should address this problem.

When naming things, let ordinary English usage guide you: plural for
collections (lists, tuples, dicts, etc) and singular for individual values. For
example, use `files` and `file` (or even just `f` if the context is clear), not
`files` and `Files`.

Let your code breathe by putting spaces around operators and related items
(equal signs, commas, etc). It helps with readability and often editability
(latter can depend on the editor). Search for PEP8 if you want more details on
recommended naming and layout practices (PEP8 is not gospel, but it is a good
starting point).

It's often a good idea to group similar data into collections: for example,
a tuple/list/dict of `shares` rather than `sharename`, `sharename2`, `sharename3`.

When you see repetition in your code, get rid of it. It's as simple as that.
Usually, you can do this by writing a function to generalize the behavior: for
example, a function taking a `share` and returning a count. In your specific
case, the grouping of the shares in a collection provides a more direct route:
kill the repetition via a loop over that collection. And since the logic inside
the loop is just counting, you can stick the whole thing in a single `sum()`
expression (this works because `bool` is a subclass of `int`).

```
shares = (
    "\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\chia1",
    "\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\chia2",
    "I:",
)

ext = '.plot'

totalfiles = sum(
    f.endswith(ext)
    for share in shares
    for _, _, files in os.walk(share)
    for f in files
)
```

You asked about making the script less hardcoded. The most natural
way to do that is via command-line arguments and the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module.
That's a bigger topic, but the basic idea is that the share paths and the extension
(`.plot`) should be variable parameters with default values. Run the script
without arguments, and it will do the default thing. Run it with arguments
and/or options, and it will use different parameters. That's the time-tested
way to go with scripts like this, and the internet is full of examples
illustrating how to set up `argparse`.

Finally, if you intend to write more scripts as you build
your **Chia Empire**,
just adopt the practice of putting all code inside of functions.
It might seem like an unnecessary hassle at first, but this
is another one of those time-tested ideas. The benefits are
numerous. Here's the basic structure:

```
import sys

def main(args):
    # Program starts here.
    print(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to edit my code according to your inputs! Looks much better and feels more smooth.

Answer (score 0):

## Raw Strings

Your code currently suffers from [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).  The directory separator backslash `\` in Windows paths needs to be escaped in strings (`\\`) to avoid being mistaken for an escape sequence like `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, or `\x`.  A similar problem happens with regular expressions, which use the backslash to introduce terms like whitespace (`\s`).

Python provides us with Raw Strings, allowing us to avoid doubling all backslash.  Simply proceeding a string with `r` enables the raw mode, where backslashes are not escapes -- they are just backslashes.

```py
sharename="\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\chia1"
sharename2="\\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\chia2"
```

becomes

```py
sharename = r"\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\chia1"
sharename2 = r"\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\chia2"
```

## Glob

Instead of using `os.walk`, you might consider using `glob.glob("**/*.plot")`, or `glob.iglob("**/*.plot")` to find and return just your desired `.plot` files.

Perhaps better, use the newer `pathlib` library, and use `.rglob("*.plot")` to recursively find the `*.plot` files:

```py
from pathlib import Path

shares = (
    Path(r"\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\chia1"),
    Path(r"\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\chia2"),
    Path("I:"),
    )

pattern = '*.plot'

total_files = sum(1
                 for share in shares 
                 for _ in share.rglob(pattern))
```

## Unused

```
printoutput = ('{}{}'.format(result, totalfiles))
```

is never used, and can be removed.

## F-strings

The formatting code ...

```
print('{}{}'.format(result, totalfiles))
```

is hard to read.  The reader has to match the first `{}` with the first argument in `.format(...)`, the second with second and so on.

Python 3.6 introduces f-strings (`f"..."`), which allow you to embed variables (or expressions) directly in the formatting string:

```
print(f'{result}{total_files}')
```

Of course, the `result` variable is not necessary:

```
print(f':page_facing_up: Total number of plots: {total_files}')
```

Alternately, if you wanted the `print_output` variable for other purposes:

```
print_output = f':page_facing_up: Total number of plots: {total_files}'
print(print_output)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I highly appreciate your input, very easy to understand and provided huge amounts of info, I will review this and try and apply it to my own code from scratch. Dont just simply like to copy and paste, that defeates the purpose of learning!